# Hacker rank The Minion Game

Tags: python

my code for this tasks passed all test cases except the strings which are  very long .
it says "Time limit exceeded" . is there any way to success that steps.

this is the link of problem

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game/problem?isFullScreen=true

```
from collections import defaultdict

def minion_game(string):
    vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}
    substrings = (string[i:j] for i in range(len(string)) for j in range(i+1, len(string)+1))
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for s in substrings:
        counts[s] += 1
    kevinpoints = sum(counts[s] for s in counts if s[0] in vowels)
    Stuartpoints = sum(counts[s] for s in counts if s[0] not in vowels)
    if kevinpoints > Stuartpoints:
        print('Kevin ' + str(kevinpoints))
    elif kevinpoints < Stuartpoints:
        print('Stuart ' + str(Stuartpoints))
    else:
        print('Draw')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    minion_game(s)
```

Comment: An explanation of what you want your code to do, and a copy of the error, would help us understand your problem.

Comment: Please include a description of what the code is supposed to do, "Hacker rank The Minion Game" is unlikely to be clear to the average reader of your post. And a [mre] including an example input that triggers the problem. "takes too long on an unknown input" is not something we can work with.

Comment: Anyway, taking too long on large inputs is generally a sign that your approach is not right and you should look for a different solution.

Comment: sorry for that , I updated it

Comment: You have added a link to an external resource that requires a login and agreeing to some terms and that can go away at any time. Please make your question self-contained and not reliant on things in the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

You surely don't need to create all the substrings and all the other loops. You simply can count the substrings beginning with vowels and consonants and compare their count. Solution [here](https://shounaklohokare.medium.com/the-minion-game-hackerrank-solution-in-python-956e21bd7ae1)